# Call Coffeescript global variable in method

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

My question basically refers to this example:

https://github.com/vlandham/vlandham.github.com/blob/master/vis/gates/coffee/vis.coffee

At the end of this script (on line 202) it calls the (view_type) parameter from the front end and based on the view type ('year' or 'all') renders the exact method. I need to implement the a similar strategy, but within the show_details() method of this script (on line 176)..What I precisely need is to retrieve the view_type in the show_details() method and based on the view type ('year' or 'all') decide what the content variable (in show_details() method) should display..any ideas or help will be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So cofeescript automatically inserts local var statements for any variable referenced inside a function (precisely to prevent global leakage that JavaScript causes by default). This means you have to explicitly pollute some global namespace which in a browser would be the window object. Nothing in CofeeScript will prevent you from assigning a field of your choice with what ever value you need and reading it back any time you need. Note that this is messy and prevented for a reason (its hard to keep this kind of code clean, also there is no window object in a server side envrionment like node.js), but it will work.